# How to set correct directory path in add_subdirectory function?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake

Using Android Studio and have two libraries, Lib(A) and Lib(B), there are two CMakeList.txt for each project.

I want to know how can I set add_subdirectory in Lib(A) because in run mode can not detect function in Lib(B), I guess the compiler/Gradle ignores CMakelist of Lib(B).

libraries structure:

```
 A
 |--src
    |--main
       |--JAVA
       |--CPP
          |-CMakelist.txt
          |-...CPP
```

and

```
 B
 |--src
    |--main
       |--JAVA
       |--CPP
          |-CMakelist.txt
          |-...CPP
```

Lib(A) CMakelist:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)
project("A")
add_subdirectory("src/main/cpp/")
add_library(A
        SHARED
        a.cpp)

find_library(log-lib
             log )
target_link_libraries(Services
                   ${log-lib} )
```

Lib(B) CMakelist:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)
project("B")
add_library(B
        SHARED
        b.cpp)

find_library(log-lib
             log )
```

I tested:

```
  add_subdirectory("src/main/cpp/")
  and
  add_subdirectory("com.myapp.B/src/main/cpp/")
```

but doesn't work, the error is:

```
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "src/main/cpp/" which is not an existing
  directory.
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any directories named `src` or `main`, so what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @AlexReinking sorry, fixed the path

Comment: `add_subdirectory` is relative to the current CMakeLists.txt, not the root of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of `add_subdirectory` takes the path to the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file to include. If this path is relative, it's resolved relative to the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` currently being parsed.

If you specify an absolute path or a relative path navigating to a parent directory, you need to specify the build directory to use as second argument.

```
add_subdirectory(../../../../B/src/main/CPP B_build)
```